# jQuery keyup function doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

My HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>
    Login
  </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class=loginForm>
  <p>Worker-ID:<input type=text id=workerID name=workerID /></p>
  <p>Password:<input type=password  id=workerPassword name=workerPassword /></p>
  <input type=submit id=submitLogin name=submitLogin value="Log in"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My scripts.js:

```
$('#workerID').keyup(function() {
    alert('key up');
);
```

It doesn't work at all. I tried everything space,one letter, numbers. The alert doesn't show up. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Always look for error messages in your browser's developer console first

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apart from a typo around your missing `}`, when your `script.js` file runs (in the `<head>` section), the rest of your document does not exist. The easiest way to work around this is to wrap your script in a document ready handler, eg

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#workerID').on('keyup', function() {
        alert('key up');
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could move your script to the bottom of the document, eg

```
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

or use event delegation which allows you to bind events to a parent element (or the document), eg

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#workerID', function() {
    alert('key up');
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works now :) I moved it to the end and it works!! Should I always put javascripts and jquery at the end or what do you suggest?

Comment: THANK YOU! $(document).on('keyup', '#workerID', function() worked for me where everything else didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the curly bracket to close the function:

```
$('#workerID').keyup(function() {
    alert('key up');
});
```

Errors like these are usually seen in the browser's JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1):

in HTML

inser id, name,vale in `" "`

```
<div class="loginForm">
  <p>Worker-ID:<input type="text" id="workerID" name="workerID" /></p>
  <p>Password:<input type="password"  id="workerPassword" name="workerPassword" /></p>
  <input type="submit" id="submitLogin" name="submitLogin" value="Log in"/>
</div>
```

in js

```
$('#workerID').keyup(function() {
       alert('key up');} // here you forget "}"
      );
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/QYgrx/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong   [**see here**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#workerID" ).keyup(function() {
    .....................
   });
});
```

change   `);`  to  `});`