# JS keyup doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have a code that works on JSFiddle but not locally with chrome I'm a bit confused..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#A").keyup(function() {
    alert('this actually works');
});

</script>

....

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="A" size="22px"/> 
<input type="text" id="B" size="22px"/> 

</form>
```

Is it a problem of JQuery's version ?

Comment: jquery-1.12.0.min.js is this file in the same directory as your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do that :

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#have', function() {
    alert('key up');
});
```

[jQuery keyup function doesnt work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373455/jquery-keyup-function-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a CDN if you have internet connection

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

or in your case

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```